# How do I find the previous state from a statesman state machine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, state-machine

I am using the statesman gem to handle a project state machine in my Rails 5 Application.

https://github.com/gocardless/statesman

I can find the current state with:

`project.state_machine.current_state`

I would expect to find something like:

`project.state_machine.previous_state`

The `to_state` is stored in the transition table in the DB, but no `from_state`. I assume this could be deduced from:

```
 previous_state = project.transitions.where(most_recent: false).last.to_state
```

I would have thought that this would be something required by everybody, is there a method available that I am not seeing here? Or does this feature not exist?

Comment: Did you try using this? `Machine#last_transition` which returns `Returns the most recent transition object`.

Comment: Yes, that gives me the last transition, and not the last state.

Comment: Look at this gem https://github.com/aasm/aasm#callbacks

It has `from_state` and `to_state`

Comment: Can't you get the state from the last transition?

Comment: Nope. The DB stores `to_state` but not `from_state`

 `previous_state = project.transitions.where(most_recent: false).last.to_state || project.initial_state` is the only way to do it that I can see, hence why asked this question.

Comment: Can't you add a metadata to the last transition. See this `Accessing metadata from the last transition` 
 `model_instance.last_transition.metadata["foo"]`

Comment: You could, but I wouldn't consider the previous state as metadata. Seems a bit crazy to put something in custom metadata when in other state machines it is a feature.

Comment: I know that. Is it not possible to just create a field previous state in order transition and update it in after transition for now. I see that you have raised an issue here as [well](https://github.com/gocardless/statesman/issues/263)

Comment: I think I am going to do `previous_state = project.transitions.where(most_recent: false).last.to_state || initial_state` for now. 

Will be the least destructive.